# Question about how to make a filter using script

Tags: linux, shell, batch-file, filter

I'm trying to make a filter on script to make this happen:

Before:

```
123.125.66.126 - - [05/Apr/2010:09:18:12 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 290
66.249.71.167 - - [05/Apr/2010:09:18:13 -0300] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 290
66.249.71.167 - - [05/Apr/2010:09:18:13 -0300] "GET /~leonardo_campos/IFBA/Web_Design_Aula_17.pdf HTTP/1.1" 404 324
```

After:

```
[05/Apr/2010:09:18:12 -0300] / 302 290
[05/Apr/2010:09:18:13 -0300] /robots.txt 404 290
[05/Apr/2010:09:18:13 -0300] /~leonardo_campos/IFBA/Web_Design_Aula_17.pdf 404 324
```

If someone could help it would be great...

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supporting all HTTP methods:

```
sed 's#.*\(\[[^]]*\]\).*"[A-Z]* \(.*\) HTTP/[0-9.]*" \(.*\)#\1 \2 \3#'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems a perfect work for "sed".

You can easily construct a pair of "s" replacement patterns to remove the unwanted pieces of lines.

Answer (score 1):

sed is your friend here, with regexps.

```
sed 's/^\(\[.*\]\) "GET \(.*\) .*" \(.*\)$/\1 \2 \3/'
```

Answer (score 1):

if your file structure is always like that, you can just use fields. no need complex regex

```
$ awk '{print $4,$5,$7,$9,$10}' file
[05/Apr/2010:09:18:12 -0300] / 302 290
[05/Apr/2010:09:18:13 -0300] /robots.txt 404 290
[05/Apr/2010:09:18:13 -0300] /~leonardo_campos/IFBA/Web_Design_Aula_17.pdf 404 324
```